Zip without preserve permissions
I'm trying to pack files into zip archive without preserving their original permissions. When i do it in Windows (by system util or with 7zip) it doesn't save this info. But when i archive same folder from Ubuntu 22.04 I'm getting new property for each file and directory, that stores original permissions. I can see it in Ark - there are 2 archives on screenshot, top one zipped on Windows and bottom on Ubuntu - comparing 2 archives in Ark
I need it because my colleagues had some problems with permissions after unpacking my archive, that weren't with windows-packed ones. So I tried to use flag -X for zip command like
zip -X testZip.zip ./index.html 

but permissions still there. Didn't found any commands to clean them from zipped folder, may be need to use another compress tool, but don't know which one

This is not programming related, the question asks about usage of a tool (zip in this case), which is off-topic. It may be on-topic on other sites though, for example [unix.se] where I found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591686/change-permissions-on-a-file-in-a-zip-without-unzipping.

What exactly are the problems your colleagues had with the presence of the permissions?

The difference with the Ubuntu-produced zip file is that the OS-created-by in the central directory will be 3, indicating Unix, and the external file attributes, a standard item of the central directory header, will be filled in for Unix. The -X option removes all extra field attributes that would be there otherwise, which in this case are the Unix timestamps. -X does not affect the external file attributes. (You will note that the zip file is a smidge smaller for -X.) This is all as it should be, per the zip format specification.
You would need to detail exactly what the problems are on the other end when unpacking, in order for anyone to provide assistance.
